# compute path integral using winding number

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Compute $\int_\gamma \! \frac{e^z-e^{-z}}{e^z-4} \, \mathrm{d}z$ and $\int_\gamma \! \frac{e^z}{z^4} \, \mathrm{d}z$ where $\gamma$ is the path $[A,B,C,D]$ for $A = 1+i$, $B=-1+i$, $C = -1 -i$, $D = 1-i$. (positively oriented rectangle)

I found that the winding number $n_\gamma(0) = 1$ and hence $\int_\gamma \! \frac{1}{z} \, \mathrm{d}x = 2\pi i$ and I should use this to proceed.

Can anyone give me a hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of the first integral, you can simply use Cauchy's theorem, since the path is null-homotopic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{z\in\mathbb{C}\,|\,e^z=4\}=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{\log 4+2k\pi i\,|\,k\in\mathbb Z\}$.

For the other integral, just use the residue theorem. It tells you that$$\int_\gamma\frac{e^z}{z^4}\,\mathrm dz=2\pi i\operatorname{res}_{z=0}\left(\frac{e^z}{z^4}\right).$$

Comment: thanks! why do you take $log2$. According to what I have in my notes $e^z-4$ should be 0 in z.

Comment: @Livpez. I made a mistake concerning the first integral and I've edit my answer. I hope that it is clear now.

Comment: To which constant path is $\gamma$ homotopic?

Comment: @Livpez $t\mapsto0$